# update to 16.04 internet unusable

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet

After an updste from 14.04 to 16.04, my wifi and eth0 became unusable at home.

When I restart, I may have a short period of connectivity but then ping to 8.8.8.8 starts lagging to about `8000ms`, browser cant connect anymore. A while later or after trying to reconnect between `eth0` and `wlan`, pings dony work at all anymore.

I'm on a think pad T440s, network manager says 'connected'. Network manager restart doesn't solve the problem.

At the university wlan it works flawlessly but not at home (its not the router though, other devices and live-cd have no problem). Problem remains after update to 16.04.

I tried to put IPV4 precedence in `/etc/gsi.conf` and changed to managed=true in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

None of this solves it, since it works at uni i guess its a DNS lookup problem but no clue how to fix it.

Also, even when disconnecting all networks, I still get the up/down arrow symbol, and the network manager connection information states that I have as Active Network Connections a tun0, with Interface: tun0 and driver: tun; ip address: 10.8.0.6 (which I can ping)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out something broke in my openvpn setup with the update, and at the same time the openvpn configuration was reset to start the service upon login, without my being aware of it. I turned of the dysfunctional openvpn process and disabled the service in `/etc/default/openvpn`, (Autostart="none") and the internet worked again; Hallelujah.